# How to access control instances from map instance in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

I need a way to access a registered control instance from Mapbox map instance.

For example, say I register a hypothetical Mapbox control:

```
const control = new IControl(); // Where IControl is the hypothetical mapbox control

map.addControl(control);
```

How do I access this `control` instance in some other places in my codebase where I only have access to the map instance??

For context; I need to perform some map actions depending on some values only the control instance is aware of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this. But there is nothing preventing you from doing:

```
map.addControl(control);
map._myControl = control;
```

and later accessing it with `map._myControl`;.